# Fatal error in K2 Tools Module

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, k2, joomla-3.6, fatal-error

Every so often, I get this error in one of the sites I manage:

```
[16-Dec-2016 17:08:20 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  require_once(/path/to/site/modules/mod_k2_toolsDShelper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/site/modules/mod_k2_tools/mod_k2_tools.php on line 19
[16-Dec-2016 17:08:20 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/path/to/site/modules/mod_k2_toolsDShelper.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /path/to/site/modules/mod_k2_tools/mod_k2_tools.php on line 19
```

This error first occurred on September 29 and has occurred many more times in the `error_log` since. Here is line 19 of `mod_k2_tools.php`:

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php');
```

Since `/path/to/site/modules/mod_k2_toolsDShelper.php` DOES NOT exist on the server, I'm guessing the actual path should be `/path/to/site/modules/mod_k2_tools/helper.php` since that file DOES exist.

What should be the correct reference to this file?

---

Note: I will pass this info on to the [JoomlaWorks](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free/k2) team in a bug report if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed:

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php');
```

To:

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__).'/'.'helper.php');
```

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/getk2/k2/issues/371) and an official solution should be given in the next K2 update.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Joomla 3.x, then do the following:

- Create a `defines.php` file at the main website directory.
- Add the following code to it:

  ```
  <?php define('DS', '/'); ?>
  ```

This should solve your problem...